# .map is only working on 1st element when returning the card in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

The Arrays.map is only working for the first object of the array .

This the is the main Function :-

```
function App(){

    return (
        <div>
            <NavBar />
            {
                data.map((prop) => {
                    return  <Card img = {prop.img} title = {prop.title} />
                })
            };
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(App() , document.getElementById('root'));
```

The Card that is supposed to take different values from map function :-

```
export default function Card({img , title}){

    return (
        <div id = "card">
            <div id = "card-image">
                <img src = {img} alt = "capy1"></img>
            </div>
            <div id = "card-info">
                <span id = "card-title"><h3>{title}</h3></span>
                <span>
                    <h4>Weight : </h4>
                    <p>

                    </p>
                </span>
                <span>
                    <h4>
                        Height :
                    </h4>
                    <p>

                    </p>
                </span>
                <span>
                    <h4>
                        Description :
                    </h4>
                    <p>

                    </p>
                </span>

            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The Data that is being passed is :-

```
const data = [
    {
      title: "GOD OF CAPYS",
      img: "./resources/capy1.jpg"
    },
    {
      title: "Black CAPYS",
      img: "./resources/black_capy.jpg"
    }
  ];
  
export default data;
```

The Output is just the first card . The 2nd card is not rendering maybe because its now getting the data from the array.

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the warnings about missing `key` props. Why?

Comment: Why are you using App as function call instead of `<App />` syntax?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
  {
                data.map((prop)=>{
                    return (
                        <Card key={prop.title} img={prop.img} title={prop.title}/>
                    )
                })
            }
```

*However i recommend using index as key*

```
{
                    data.map((prop, index)=>{
                        return (
                            <Card key={index} img={prop.img} title={prop.title}/>
                        )
                    })
                }
```

*works fine for me in both ways!!*

Comment: This does not answer the question